# Protractor - MacOS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jasmine, protractor

Hi everybody: I have some issues in Protractor.

I'm new trying to config Protractor in Mac with VSCode (I couldn't to that with Eclipse, it was really hard to do)
I'm creating a project from the beginning with Protractor.

I have created a conf.js file:

```
export const config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    specs: ['specs/*.spec.js'],
    onPrepare: function(){
    // Getting CLI report
          const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
          spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true
          }
        }));
    //Getting XML report
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
           consolidateAll: true,
           filePrefix: 'guitest-xmloutput',
           savePath: '.'
        }));
    //Getting screenshots
      var fs = require('fs-extra');
        fs.emptyDir('screenshots/', function (err) {
                 console.log(err);
             });
             jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
                 specDone: function(result) {
                     if (result.status == 'failed') {
                         browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                             var browserName = caps.get('browserName');
                             browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                                 var stream = fs.createWriteStream('screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName+ '.png');
                                 stream.write(new Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
                                 stream.end();
                             });
                         });
                     }
                 }
             });
    },
      onComplete: function() {
    //Getting HTML report
    var browserName, browserVersion;
         var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
         capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            browserName = caps.get('browserName');
            browserVersion = caps.get('version');
            platform = caps.get('platform');
            var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
            testConfig = {
                reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
                outputPath: './',
                outputFilename: 'ProtractorTestReport',
                screenshotPath: './screenshots',
                testBrowser: browserName,
                browserVersion: browserVersion,
                modifiedSuiteName: false,
                screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
                testPlatform: platform
            };
            new HTMLReport().from('guitest-xmloutput.xml', testConfig);
        });
      }
}
```

This is my json file:

```
 {
  "name": "protractor_initium",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Final Protractor Framework",
  "allowJs": true,
  "main": "conf.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rodrigo González",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.14",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-html-reporter-2": "^1.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

My babel file:

```
    newFunction()

function newFunction() {
  {
    "presets";
    ["@babel/preset-env"];
  }
}
```

My installed software:

```
npm: 6.12.1
node: v13.1.0
Protractor: 5.4.2
Java:. openjdk version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

After run protractor conf.js I have the next issue:

```
[14:53:01] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[14:53:01] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[14:53:01] E/configParser - /Users/rodrigo.g/Documents/VS_Workspace/Protractor_Initium/conf.js:1
export const config = {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1091:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js:135:26)
    at Object.initFn [as init] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js:93:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js:226:10)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score -1):

The error is straight forward.

Your first line of conf.js should've been

```
exports.config = {
```

for javascript, or

```
export interface Config {
```

for typescript

Comment: I already changed for exports.config = { but there is a pop up that says file is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module. (ts 80001)